# WHERE Statement - Multiple conditions - adding 2 more

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can't quite get my conditions correct to alter an existing query that works.

```
SELECT  dd.GasYear,D.DealCash_IsAgency,D.DealCash_IsNetBack, dd.GasYearName,dd.MonthName,dd.Season,dd.FirstOfMonthDate,Deal_OrigDate,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Deal_OrigDate) AS Orig_DayofWeek
   ,Deal_StartDate,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Deal_StartDate) AS Start_DayofWeek,Deal_StopDate,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Deal_StopDate) AS Stop_DayofWeek
   ,CASE
        WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(d, Deal_StartDate, Deal_StopDate) AS CHAR(10)) > 6 THEN 'All Other'
    END AS DealType
   ,Deal_Owner,d.Deal_Id,CP_Cmp_ShortName
   ,CASE
        WHEN Qty_MeasurementType_Short = 'GJ' THEN DealCashTran_Qty / 2.055098
        ELSE DealCashTran_Qty
    END DealCashTran_Dth_Qty
FROM uvDealCash d
LEFT OUTER JOIN uvDealCashTran AS dct
    ON d.Deal_Id = dct.Deal_Id
INNER JOIN Cmp c
    ON d.CP_Cmp_ShortName = c.Cmp_ShortName
INNER JOIN [uvCmp_CmpType_CmpCPType] ct
    ON c.Cmp_Id = ct.Cmp_Id
INNER JOIN BISandbox.dbo.dimDate dd
    ON d.Deal_StartDate = dd.FullDate
WHERE ((Deal_Owner IN ('TYK', 'JTT', 'MML', 'CGG', 'LIO', 'MAT')
AND ct.CmpCPType_Descript = 'Producer')
--US Entities Kristen's wants added 
OR (CP_Cmp_ShortName IN ('SEV', 'CNAT', 'TNMKT', 'CENT')))
AND Deal_LengthInMonths >= 0
AND DATEDIFF(d, Deal_StartDate, Deal_StopDate) > 6
AND Deal_StartDate > '4/1/2018'    --=<Parameters.StartDate>    
AND DealPurchaseSellType_Short = 'P'
AND d.DealCashType_Short IN ('DFM', 'FM')
```

In addition to the above I want to exclude results if DealCash_IsAgency = 1 or D.DealCash_IsNetBack = 1

I tried several variations by adding this to the end of the existing WHERE statement.

```
--exclude AMA and NB 
AND (D.DealCash_IsAgency = 1 OR D.DealCash_IsNetBack = 1)
```

It still returns rows with 1's in both of the columns.

Greatly appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to exclude then you have to add a condition like this by adding `not`:

```
AND NOT (D.DealCash_IsAgency = 1 OR D.DealCash_IsNetBack = 1)
```